# Missing css, js files after Magento 2 install

Tags: magento2

I try to install Magento 2 and I have a problem with css and js loading (they are missing). There are a lot of topics about this problem and it seems that the last step of the solution is to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command (rebuild the static content).

Ok, but how? I have no access to the terminal at my host (actually I don't know too much about it, I just use Magento as an average user). Is there a way to run this command inside Magento? What are the steps to run it? The installation is in a sub directory not in site root.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to deploy static-content from within the frontend or admin of Magento 2.

At the least, your hosting company should be able to run this command for you.

1. Need SSH credentials & access to your server
2. Login to server using SSH via [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(OS_X)), [putty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), etc.
3. Navigate to Magento 2 root install directory using CLI
4. Run this command:

_

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have any other options for deploying content from the admin. You need to deploy static content from the Magento root directory only then you will be able to see CSS and js.
Open your Magento 2 root directory and run the below commands:
For Windows users-
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

For linux users-
/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Another method is using ssh. For that, you need to login to Cpanel. Through command prompt login to the server using ssh credentials. Then navigate through Magento 2 root directory and run the same commands as given above.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's not a good news, the host that I use has a custom interface not like cpanel... By the way it is an "unusual" Magento "feature". I am waiting for something like a simple php script that can (re)generate static content. Thank you again.